# doctrine, symfony 1.4: How do I fix this 'Integrity constraint violation'

Tags: mysql, orm, symfony1, doctrine, foreign-keys

I have defined this entity in schema.yml

```
Jobsearch:
  tableName: jobsearch
  columns:
    seeker_id:
      primary: true
      type: integer
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    empmode:
      type: string(50)
    pensum:
      type: integer
    active:
      type: boolean
  relations:
    Privateaccount:
      local: seeker_id
      foreign: id
      alias: seeker
```

it has a foreign key reference to

```
Privateaccount:
  tableName: privateaccount
  columns:
    id:
      primary: true
      unique: true
      type: integer
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    firstname:
      type: string(255)
    lastname:
      type: string(255)
  inheritance:
    extends: sfGuardUser
    type: column_aggregation
    keyField: type
    keyValue: Privateaccount
```

I made a symfony action for testing purpose, it is supposed to save a Jobsearch to db:

```
 public function executeTest(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
   $test = new Jobsearch();
   $test->setSeeker( $this->getUser()->getGuardUser() ) ; // set the user that is logged in    
   $test->save();
  }
```

`$test->save()` results in this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`test2`.`sf_guard_user_profile`, CONSTRAINT
>   `sf_guard_user_profile_user_id_sf_guard_user_id` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`user_id`) REFERENCES `sf_guard_user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

I don't see why the foreign key constraint is failing.

What has caused the error?

EDIT: If I change `primary` to `false` in `seeker_id`, it does work. But I want the Foreign Key to be the Primary Key. If possible, how do I make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the schema.yml to

```
Jobsearch:
  tableName: jobsearch
  columns:
    seeker_id:
      primary: true
      type: integer
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    empmode:
      type: string(50)
    pensum:
      type: integer
    active:
      type: boolean
  relations:
    Seeker:
      class: Privateaccount
      local: seeker_id
```

and

```
Privateaccount:
  tableName: privateaccount
  columns:
    firstname:
      type: string(255)
    lastname:
      type: string(255)
  inheritance:
    extends: sfGuardUser
    type: column_aggregation
    keyField: type
    keyValue: Privateaccount
```

Doctrine creates the id field by default. Don't declare it.

Finally, it should work.

```
 public function executeTest(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
   $test = new Jobsearch();
   $test->setSeekerId( $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId() ) ; // set the user that is logged in    
   $test->save();
  }
```